# Magento : JQuery ias Infinite Ajax Scroll not working with filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, filter, ias

I am using the FME filter and the infinite Ajax scroll. Initially, It is working proper and bind the product as per pagination when I am selecting and deselecting product using filter.

but once if i am loading the more products after that it is not working.

http://printsutra.co.in/index.php/business-cards/transparent-cards.html

Steps:

1. Select/Deselect filter option Multiple times.
2. Click on the load more designs.

-- Now you can see load more design button hide --

I thing there is a url problem because it add the page no in the url, but i am unable to fix this issue.

Can someone help me ..?

Comment: Issue has been fixed.